# How to fix this Code, to get data from service and send it to my form using Reactive Form?

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-services, angular-forms

in my app i create a fake server to get values from it, and i use service to return all values and send it to my form.

### 1.My Html :

```
    <form [formGroup]="Field"> 
  <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Branch</th>
            <th scope="col">Realisation N-1</th>
            <th scope="col">L'objectifs</th>
            <th scope="col">Taux de Croissance</th>
        </tr>
        <tr  class="back-color">
            <td><label formControlName="nom" ></label></td>
            <td><input formControlName="realisation"   /></td>
            <td><input formControlName="objectif"      /></td>
            <td><input formControlName="TC"            /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr FormArrayName="sousbranch"> 
            <td><label formControlName="s_nom"></label></td>
            <td><input formControlName="s_realisation"  /></td>
            <td><input formControlName="s_objectif"       /></td>
            <td><input formControlName="s_TC"           /></td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

### 2.my SERVICE :

```
   baseUrl = http://localhost:3000/branche       

   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
```

//... get all branch from the server

```
     getBranches(): Observable<Ibranch[]>{        
       return this.httpClient.get<Ibranch[]>(this.baseUrl)      
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));        
        }
```

### 3.my Component Methode :

//..  Ibranch is a interface heve all branch key name 
( ..   Ibranch have an array of IsBranch)
//..  IsBranch is also an interface have all values of souBranch

```
branches : Ibranch[]; 
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private _BranchesService:BranchesService) {
}
 Field : FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.Field = this.fb.group({
      nom : [''],
      objectif : [''],
      realisation : [''],
      TC : [],
      sousbranch : this.fb.array([
          this.fb.group({
            s_nom : [],
            s_realisation : [],
            s_objectif : [],
            s_TC : []
          })
      ])
    });
  }
```

//.. subscribe to getBranches Methode :

```
 getBranche(){
    this._BranchesService.getBranches().subscribe( 
      (branch : Ibranch[]) => this.setBranch(branch['']),
      //(branch : Ibranch[]) => branch[''],
      (err : any)      => console.log(err)
    );
  } 

                   <br>
```

//.. set values to the form

```
setBranch(branche : Ibranch){
     this.Field.patchValue({
          nom : branche.nom,
          realisation : branche.Taux_de_Croissance,
          objectif : branche.objectif,
          TC : branche.Taux_de_Croissance,
     });  this.Field.setControl('sousbranch',this.setExistingSBranch(branche.sousBranch))
  }
  setExistingSBranch(branchset : Isbranch[]) : FormArray{
   const Formarray = new FormArray([]);
  branchset.forEach(b => {
    Formarray.push(this.fb.group({
       s_id : b.s_id,
       s_nom : b.s_nom,
       s_realisation : b.s_realisation,
       s_objectif : b.s_objectif,
       s_Taux_de_Croissance : b.s_Taux_de_Croissance  
     }))
   });
   return Formarray;
  }
```

notice that every branch have couple of soubranch,
and this image will explain the result that i search for it
[this is thee resulta :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFDue.jpg)

code in stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdzfrw 
but the app dont work.

thanks a lot for answering my question

Comment: Can you provide some https://stackblitz.com URL for above code...

Comment: https://angular-cdzfrw.stackblitz.io  but the app dont work

Comment: sorry i did a mistake it's : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdzfrw

Comment: Your stack blitz is broken

Comment: try this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdzfrw